# Google map event after all pins are loaded(api3)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Question is simple. On page load I have map without pins. There are control on map that enable to user to place pins on map. Sometimes number of pins that need to be placed are over 2000 and this is process that need time. My question about this is there any google map event similar to jQuery `document.ready` that could wait until all map pins are placed on map. I need to display loading overlay until all pins are placed on map and after that hide it.

Just like function for map

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
        // do something
    });
```

I try with idle but if map don't change zoom this event is not executed(this situation is possible when you add pins on map).

Comment: Consider reading the google maps [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) and the [reference api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no there is no google maps event for when all your pins are placed. However you do not need one. Just write your code so that it does these actions in this order when you load your pins:

1. apply your loading overlay
2. loop through the creation of all your pins and add them to the map
3. remove you loading overlay

If code helps you more:

```
function loadMyPins(pinDataCollection){
    addMyOverlay();

    for(var i=0; i<pinDataCollection.length; i++){
        //create new pin
    }

    removeMyOverlay();
}
```

Comment: Placing pins on map is asynchronous so removeMyOverlay(); is executed before all pins are in place(especially when you have 2000 pins). I try this but without help.

Comment: If you put removeMyOverlay() *inside* of the asynchronous it should work. Could you post the function you are calling asynchronously to load the markers? It might be easier to show you.

Comment: Google map function map.setMap() is asynchronous not my function. I just use pins from java script array and call pin[i].setMap(map) in for loop for each marker.

Comment: Just to be clear about this situation. I recap code that you post to help me to solve issue. If you add brakepoint to function that remove overlay code works fine bur after for loop is executed it take a time while pins are placed on map after that clustered  and map is fitted based on pins(This happen while I am waiting on brakepoint). This happen because google map method for placing pins and fit bounds on map are asynchronous. If I remove brakepoint my overlay is hidden before map is completely loaded.